# Unix Command to copy the unique files from one directory to another directory

Tags: unix

I have a set of files in the input directory and I need to copy only unique jar files to the another directory 
Example: A directory is having files(x.txt,y.txt,z.txt, a.jar,b.jar,c.jar,d.jar,e.jar,f.jar).

a.jar and b.jar are having same data, and d.jar,e.jar and f.jar having same data.

I want to copy only a.jar,c.jar and d.jar files into output directory
Please suggest me the solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try something like this:

```
shasum -a 256 input_dir/*.jar | sort | awk '{if($1!=p)print $2;p=$1}' |
xargs -I{} cp -vp {} output_dir/

input_dir/d.jar -> output_dir/d.jar
input_dir/c.jar -> output_dir/c.jar
input_dir/a.jar -> output_dir/a.jar
```

The idea is to compute hashes of all possible input files, and then use `sort` and `awk`to get only the first file that have the same hash.

`sort` arranges the list in a way that files with the same hash will be listed continuously, and the `awk` command removes lines where the hash matches the hash in the previous line, hence keeping only the first file for each given hash.

Note that this can become quite time consuming if you have many files or if they are big.

EDIT: pattern to match *.jar files only

Comment: Great answer (particularly given that it's your first day). Welcome to Stack Overflow!

Comment: Thanks @AnthonyGeoghegan

Comment: Thanks @secolive The script is working fine for me.   sha1sum input_dir/*.jar | sort | awk '{if($1!=p)print $2;p=$1}' |
xargs -I{} cp -vp {} output_dir/